# JcomboBox showing only one item

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jcombobox, recordset

Whats wrong with my code? the second JcomboBox is showing only one item even if there is more in the database.
This is how it should work:
The first JcomboBox is filled with data from the database, depending on user choice on the first comboBox, the second one is filled, then some Jlabels are filled with data depending on the item choosen from the second JcomboBox.

I tried if(o == comboBox2) still the same problem.

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Object o = e.getSource();
    if(o == comboBox1) {            
        Object matricule =  comboBox1.getSelectedItem();
        String sqll = "Select  * FROM clients WHERE matricule = " +matricule;               

            try {
                rs = stat.executeQuery(sqll);
                while(rs.next()) {
                    nom.setText(rs.getString("nom"));
                    prenom.setText(rs.getString("prenom"));
                    cin.setText(rs.getString("cin"));
                    adresse.setText(rs.getString("adresse"));                   
                }
            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }   

        comboBox2.removeAllItems();

        Object index = comboBox1.getSelectedItem();
        String sql = "Select  distinct p.code FROM parcelle p, clients c WHERE c.matricule = p.exploitant AND c.matricule = " +index;

            try {
                rs = stat.executeQuery(sql);
                while(rs.next()) {
                    System.out.println(rs.getInt("code"));
                    comboBox2.addItem(rs.getInt("code"));
                }
            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }           
        return;
    }       

         Object code =  comboBox2.getSelectedItem();  
         String sqll = "Select  * FROM parcelle WHERE code = " +code;  

         try {  
             rs = stat.executeQuery(sqll);                     

             while(rs.next()) {  
                 sau.setText(rs.getString("sau"));  
                 sol.setText(rs.getString("type_sol"));  
                 irrigation.setText(rs.getString("mode_irrigation"));  
                 exploitation.setText(rs.getString("type_exploitation"));                      
             }  

         } catch (SQLException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
        }       
}
```

Comment: There's more in the database, but can you confirm that your query is returning multiple rows?

Comment: Yes it is, i tried the query via phpMyAdmin and its returning all the existing rows.
http://i46.tinypic.com/2uyr6e8.jpg

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Hard-code the data.

Answer (score 1):

Can you confirm that the value for 'code' isn't null in any of the records? From the sound of things, the value for 'code' in your 2nd record is null (or anything else that can't be parsed as an int) which is causing an exception.